# How to configure spring-security with annotations (no xml)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'd like intregrate spring-security in an application that is completely configured with spring annotations, no xml is present. How would the following have to look like in pure java code?

```
  <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
  </http>
```

I cannot find any documentation on spring-security with annotations. Is it not supported so far? If not, how can I integrate a security.xml in an annotation based configuration class?

```
@Configuration
public AppConfig {

}
```

Comment: It looks like this page might help you: http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy. do something like this, important is only to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").hasRole("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")
  }
}
```